# finding value in xml and returning the value if exists in xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have seen the query to retrieve the value in XML

```
select O.*
from [Order] as O
where O.OrderXML.exist('/Order/header/status[text() = "Processing"]') = 1
```

what if i have many tags and i wants to query the above without mentioning the all tags instead i want the records which has ordered status.
suppose i have a super child tag 
and i don't want to write all tags in query instead i want to mention only tag which i am referring to.
so i want to query it in way that 'order' tag contains value"value"

Comment: You probably want to learn, how you would get different data of XML and handle it *similar to a normal table*? Search for `APPLY` in connection with `nodes()` and look, how one might use a `CTE` to create a *derived table*. If you need help on this, you must provide an example of your XML together with the expected output.

Comment: thanks got it 
select [col].exist('//CurrSIG[text()]')  as status from table let me know it their any thing wrong in this ?    @igor

Comment: I've no idea, what you are talking about... Without having seen your XML and and the expected output: How should one help you?